# Transforming data from file into a structured format (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I've just started to write little programs in Python, so my experience level is very low. At the moment I'm trying to read a file into a data structure in Python3, but I have no idea how to do it fast & easy to understand.

First, I have to explain the content of the file. There are headings and the lines following is additional information belonging to the heading.

Booklist.txt

```
Programming----------------
Python Cookbook
Python in a nutshell
Recipes--------------------
Slow Cooking
Clean Eating
Low Carb
Sports---------------------
Mastering Mountain Bike Skills
```

My idea is to have a structure like this:

```
{'Programming': ['Python Cookbook', 'Python in a nutshell'],
 'Recipes': ['Slow Cooking', 'Clean Eating', 'Low Carb'], ... }
```

So far, I did something that seems to work:

```
f = open('Booklist.txt')
myDict = dict()
for ind, line in enumerate(f):
    match = re.search(r"(^[\w ]+)([-]+)$", line)
    if match is not None:
        category = match.group(1)
        myDict[category] = []
    else:
        myDict[category].append(line)
f.close()
```

But what could I do with the index? Can I use it to sort the keys in any way? Dictionaries are unsorted, right?

Comment: OK. What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to show your code, any output you are getting, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Hint: you can use the `in` operator to check if a certain string is contained in another one. For example, `"a" in "abcd"` will return `True`.

Comment: note that `if match is not None:` equals `if match`

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill, but you can use a python PEG parser like [parsimonious](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious) to parse the `booklist.txt`. It will take you some time to learn the PEG syntax, but it is much easier to write robust code with an established library than doing everything yourself.

Basic usage:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
grammar = Grammar(
  """
  body       = ( category '\n' name+ '\n' ) +
  category   =  name '-'+
  name       = ~"[a-zA-Z]*"i
  """)

with open('booklist.txt','r') as f:
  ast = grammar.parse(f.read())

print( ast )
```

#### After SO update the question

Yes, dict is unsorted. If you want to keep the origin order, use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Also `if match is not None:` can be simplified to `if match:`

Comment: For whoever downvoted: when I start writing the post , the SO didn't provide any code yet, nor the question.